# xml serialization for string containing xhtml content

Tags: c#, xml

My xml file contains data like

```
<THE-VALUE><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <h1 class="firstHeading" id="firstHeading">Starbucks</h1><img alt="Embedded image" id="_1378207355918" src="_f6e2e77a-904d-4526-a215-660955f56377?accept=none&amp;private"/><p id="_1378207355840"><br/></p> </div></THE-VALUE>
```

Thus my xml file has a tag that contains xhtml content.

I have no control over this file as I am receiving this file from other sources. Now while deserializing using XmlSerializer, I am facing problem.

I know this query has been posted earlier also. But I couldn't find any satisfactory answer. Can someone suggest any solution? Should I implement IXmlSerializable?

Answer (score 0):

This may not exactly answer your question, but it will probably get you on the right track.  Per your question, this person *did* use IXmlSerializable in their example and showed how to use it in a case similar to yours.  It seems that it would be easily adaptable to your situation:

[Deserialize element value as string although it contains mixed content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730764/deserialize-element-value-as-string-although-it-contains-mixed-content)