# C# xml schema deserialization with html part as string

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

My xml looks like this:

```
<document>
    <body>
        <p>
            <text>asdasdasdasd</text>
        </p>
        <text>  </text>
        <p>
            <text>Bl abloa blasdasdasd</text>
        </p>
    </body>     
</document>
```

So what i want to do is to parse body element as string.

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "document")]
    public class Document
    {      
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "body")]
        public string Body { get; set; }   
    }
```

I've tried [XmlText] and different attributes on like this [XmlText(Type = typeof(string))]

I'm trying to do this directly as a parameter in my controller method:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task SearchResult([FromBody] SearchResultDataContract searchResult)
    {
        try
```

Were SearchResultDataContract is the document object.

But I haven't managed to find any solutions.

Comment: you want whole `<body>....</body>` node as string or only want `<text>` node inside?

Comment: Easiest would have been the whole body node as a string :) @er-mfahhgk

Answer (score 2):

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "document")]
public class Document
{
    [XmlElement("body")]
    public XmlElement Body { get; set; }
}
```

should work, as long as we're talking about xhtml, not html. You can't deal with `string` directly, AFAIK - the encoder won't trust you that your xml will always be well-formed - but it trusts `XmlElement`. You could always add something that shims between the two, if needed.

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to do this for hours! Great solution, from xmlelement i can just grab the innerXml to get it as a string. Thanks :)

Comment: Hmm it seems that outerXml only gives me the first node "<p>" and not the other nodes inside of body... Do you know why?

Comment: @DanielGustafsson oh eesh, that's vexing; but I guess it makes sense... I ... don't have good solutions in that case; I'll delete this answer

Comment: ooh no :( Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by creating my own extension for the deserialization using this: 
[Deserialize element value as string although it contains mixed content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730764/deserialize-element-value-as-string-although-it-contains-mixed-content)